# Subversion repo inside a repo

Tags: svn, repository

It appears that some bright soul has created a repo inside of an existing repo.

Will this work? Are there any problems that might result from this?

**UPDATE 001:**

As requested, here is a list of the repository directory where a new repository appears to have been created. I did not create this. I have files in other parts of the same repo.

Will this work? Are there any pitfalls?

```
PS C:\> svn ls https://fugu.company.com/db/trunk/Scripts/DR01
ProjRAF/
ProjRAF_Staging/
... <several more directories>
ProjDocData/
ProjCleanup
Desktop.ini
MSDB/
Master/
README.txt
Shared/
Tools/
conf/
db/
format
hooks/
locks/
svn.ico
PS C:\>
```

Comment: please specify what kind of repo.  

perhaps a short output from the ‘ls’ command. 

To the trained eye, we know what you’re talking about but this here is StackExchange and we like to show readers what it looks like and what commands were used.

Comment: @JohnGreene, I have added a directory list where the repo in a repo was created.